# Using PSPDFKIT, how to override a PSPDFDrawView class to add a touch event function?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PSPDFKit
import PSPDFKitUI

class SignatureDrawView: PSPDFDrawView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        strokeColor = .red
        inputMode = .draw
        backgroundColor = .black

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
         isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        strokeColor = .red
        inputMode = .draw
        backgroundColor = .black


    }

    override func startDrawing(at location: PSPDFDrawingPoint) {

    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    }
}
```

and this my **PSPDFSignatureViewController** class:

```
import UIKit
import PSPDFKit
import PSPDFKitUI

class PSPDFDigitalSignatureViewController: 
PSPDFSignatureViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
}
override var signer: PSPDFSigner? {        
let p12URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "JohnAppleseed", withExtension: "p12")!
let p12data = try! Data(contentsOf: p12URL)
let p12 = PSPDFPKCS12(data: p12data)
return PSPDFPKCS12Signer(displayName: "John Appleseed", pkcs12: p12)
    }
override var drawView: SignatureDrawView{
let drawView = SignatureDrawView.init(frame:  CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
drawView.backgroundColor = .gray
return drawView
    }
override var certificateSelectionMode: PSPDFSignatureCertificateSelectionMode {
get { return .never }
set {}
}

override var savingStrategy: PSPDFSignatureSavingStrategy {
get { return .neverSave }
set {}
}
}
```

I am trying to build an app with digital signature with ink in PDF file.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the class via the documented mechanism? https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/getting-started/overriding-classes/

Comment: PSPDFKit team member here. If you're looking to get such information from the Apple Pencil, subclassing `PSPDFDrawView` won't help. You can, however, get the Ink annotation lines out of the signature, through `-[PSPDFSignatureViewController lines]`. 

In the future, please reach out to pspdfkit.com/support/request and our support team will help you in there.